# Delete records that are older than a day

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table of links. If the link was generated and then the next day it is still in the table than I want to delete it. If there are multiple rows I want to remove each row.My query is:

```
DELETE FROM resetpassword WHERE expiry_timestamp < DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

but this gives me an error:

```
com.web.command.exceptions.DatabaseException:
  "DAY" is not valid in the context where it is used.
```

How do I remove all rows that are a day old?

**EDIT**

`expiry_timestamp` is a `timestamp` so I think the query should be something like the below, but I still can't get it to work.

```
select * from resetpassword
where timestamp(expiry_timestamp) = timestamp(current date) - 1 days
```

Comment: I don't know IMB's RDBMS, but standard SQL should be `DELETE FROM resetpassword...` rather than `DELETE resetpassword...`

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:ibm] tag, but rather the specific database (my guess is that it's [tag:db2]).

Comment: Is the datatype on expiry_timestamp a datetime?  Because this query should work as-is.  It parses and executes in my t-SQL window.

Comment: My assumption is the method that you are using to pass this query to your database is incorrect. Since it is saying day is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: this is a DB2 specific answer.

Okay, this post here: http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1637371-help-there-dateadd-function-db2.html

(and this post agrees):  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html

says you can do:

```
   DELETE FROM resetpassword WHERE expiry_timestamp < (current date - 1 DAYS)
```

Comment: I get this error when I use that query:

No authorized routine named "GETDATE" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.16.53

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that.  Try the edited version I just put together.  I've been monkeying with the syntax a bit, reload.

Comment: And while I'm recommending things I suggest using a SELECT * instead of a delete while testing.  Copy-pasting random stuff people tell you to do on the Interwebs is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: I inserted dumby data into the database then I deleted it,that way I knew what I was removing and I didn't wipe out a whole table.

Answer (score 0):

If expiry_timestamp is defined as a timestamp, you should

```
DELETE FROM resetpassword WHERE expiry_timestamp < CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 1 day
```

It is generally better to avoid type conversion (such as timestamp to date) unless there is some need to do so.

Comment: Except, as `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` has some time portion, if he wants to clear out _everything_ for a specified day he has to set the time portion to 0.  I'd most likely just have cast the results of the date math to `TIMESTAMP` if I wanted to avoid the conversion.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Let's look at an example. There's a record that has an expiration of 2014-01-20-09.30.00 and we run the query at 11am on 2014-01-21. It's been over 24 hours. The predicate in my answer will delete the record.  But `date(expiry_timestamp) < current date - 1 day` evaluates to false.

Comment: Yeah, of course.  I meant something along the lines of `expiry_timestamp < TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - 1 DAY)`.  I guess it depends on whether the OP is wanting to delete things in single-day chunks, versus 24 hours back; there's cases for each.  I just read the question as being about individual days, not as a strict 24 hour time-frame.

Comment: Right, it depends on how the "a day old" requirement is interpreted. But when you mentioned "everything for a specified day", I thought you might have been implying the conversion to a date would delete more records, when actually it would delete fewer.  But if you change the comparison from `<` to `<=`, then just after midnight you might delete records whose timestamp was only a few minutes old.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be an answer:

```
DELETE FROM resetpassword WHERE expiry_timestamp < DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE());
```